# Inner join in Yii2 - trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I'm trying to link two tables: employees and departments, when each employee is a member of one department. Then I'll retrieve some information using the "department_id" field from both tables, "type" field from "departments" and "section" field from "departments". I've done it before using vanilla PHP and SQL, but now I have to implement it to Yii2.

I started with adding relations in the view. Then I tried to link those tables using Yii2 functions like innerJoinWhere etc. When this failed, I tried executing raw SQL in Yii, but that didn't help.

Every snippet is from the view.

Relations:

```php
class Employee extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
    public static function tableName(){
        return 'employees';
    }

    public function getDepartments(){
        return $this->hasOne(Departments::className(), ['department_id' => 'department_id']);
    }
}

class Departments extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
    public static function tableName(){
        return 'departments';
    }
    public function getEmployee(){
        return $this->hasOne(Employee::className(), ['department_id' => 'department_id']);
    }
}
```

The SQL line that I tried to reproduce ($dep and $sec are some variables that are irrelevant right now):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT departments.type, departments.department FROM departments
 INNER JOIN employees ON department.department_id = employees.department_id
 WHERE departments.department_id = '$dep' AND departments.section = '$sec'
```

First attempt (Yii2 functions):

```php
$result = Departments::find()
    ->select(['departments.type', 'departments.department_id'])
    ->innerJoin('employees', '`employees`.`department_id` =  `departments`.`department_id`')
    ->where(['departments.department_id' => $dep])
    ->andwhere(['departments.section' => $sec])
    ->with('employees')
    ->one();
```

Second attempt (raw SQL):

```php
$connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
$command = $connection->createCommand("..."); //same as above
$result= $command->queryOne();
```

Finally, I need to retrieve the information:

```php
$type = $result->type;
//etc.
```

The error message is the same for both attempts:

> Trying to get property of non-object, when the last line of above is
>   executed.

Comment: have you tried to var_dump $result? getPracownicy() Should be getEmployee()?

Comment: Yes. It outputs correct data (after commenting the last line to avoid errors), so I'm even more confused right now.

```php
array(2) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(1) "o"
  ["department"]=>
  string(20) "IT"
}
```

getPracownicy is just a translation error, I'll edit it. Completely irrelevant, but thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Ok $result->type should be $result['type'], in this case $result it's not an object

Comment: Works as a charm. Thank you!